# A group of + verb?

Tags: verb-agreement

I am not sure if "is" can be the right verb to go since the context is plural. please look at the following sentence...

"a group of so-called meshless or mesh-free methods have become one of the hottest areas of research in computational mechanics"

Comment: Since you're defining *a group*, you can replace *have become* by *is* because *of so-called meshless or mesh-free methods* is an adjective-like phrase.

Comment: You mention "is" in the first sentence, but it's not present in the last sentence.